# How to invoke a powershell ise and also run a few command line from powershell tab from C#?

Tags: c#, powershell

Been googling to find some sample code how to invoke "powershell ise" in specific with a few powershell tabs to run a few command in parallel from C#. Have not very fruitful with the search. Any link or any code snippet that you could share?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with this? The ISE profile is usually the place to add your custom settings and whatnot in order to set the environment up to your liking. For running powershell stuff in general, go with powershell.exe - or better yet, if triggered from C# code, import and use the appropriate DLL for the job (`System.Management.Automation.dll`). There's basically too much guesswork for me to give you a better answer to the question at this point.

Comment: There is a few non intuitive personnel using the similar automation, they would like to personnelly inspect the error/result after the each command is invoke on the powershell tab.

Comment: have use System.Management.Automation.dll but I am not sure how to fire up the ise and all the interaction is hidden from the user.

Comment: You might want to look into using breakpoints for instance to debug scripts that you run interactively. `$Error[0] | select *` comes to mind right away for examining the last error. Proper error handling in the script, using try/catch/finally etc probably wouldn't be amiss either. I'm not quite sure where the tabs comes into the picture here though.